# What is the kohana framework used for?

Tags: kohana, principles

I´m learning kohana for the first time and need to know some basic facts about the mcv principle.
Up until now i´ve only used Javascript frameworks (ext, openlayers etc) which are referenced in the headers of html pages. The classes are then extracted and used in applications. I can have as many separate applications referencing one Ext.js framework installation as I like.

Kohana,as an mvc framework, is obviously different, but which purpose does it fullfill? Is it used to create web applications inside the Kohana installation ie. one web application...or is it used to create an endless number of applications? As far as I can see, one downloads the kohana framework, and adapts/extends the framework to make an application..e.g. a web cms. Am I on the right lines?

cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, typically each web application has its own copy of a library. So, one copy of Kohana is extended to one web app.

MVC is a pattern that is common in web frameworks. It leads to better code reuse and lose coupling among different parts of the app.

Answer (score 2):

The Kohana framework is typically used to build a web application. You would normally use one Kohana install and work with that to make a web application.

You could if you wanted, install Kohana centrally in somewhere like /usr/share/Kohana
Then you would move the application folder out and set the update the paths in index.php to the right places (there is a system path, module path and application path).

MVC allows is a design pattern for separation of business logic (model), controller (uses the model to get data and pass it to the view) and the view normally is what is outputted to the browser (HTML). You can read more here

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller